# simulate data from a linear fractional stable motion

Tags: r, matlab, fft

I have to simulate some data from a Linear fractional stable motion. I have found an article where they simulate such data using Matlab. The code is from the article "Simulation methods for linear fractional stable motion and
FARIMA using the Fast Fourier Transform" by Stilian Stoev and Murad S. Taqqu. The following is the matlab code:

```
% Written by Stilian Stoev 05.06.2002, sstoev@math.bu.edu
%
% Usage:
% y = fftlfsn(H,alpha,m,M,C,N,n)
%
mh = 1/m;
d = H-1/alpha;
t0 = [mh:mh:1];
t1 = [1+mh:mh:M];
A = mh^(1/alpha)*[t0.^d, t1.^d-(t1-1).^d];
C = C*(sum(abs(A).^alpha)^(-1/alpha));
A = C*A;
Na = m*(M+N);
A = fft(A,Na);
y = [];
for i=1:n,
if alpha<2,
Z = rstab(alpha,0,Na)’;
elseif alpha==2,
Z = randn(1,Na);
end;
Z = fft(Z,Na);
w = real(ifft(Z.*A,Na));
y = [y; w(1:m:N*m)];
end;
```

Example:
The commands

```
H = 0.2; alpha =1.5; m = 256; M = 6000; N = 2^14 - M;
y = fftlfsn(H,alpha,m,M,1,N,1);
x = cumsum(y);
```

generate a simulated path y of length N of linear 
fractional stable noise and a path x of LFSM.

In the following I have tried to translate it, 
but I have some questions. I have commented on it in the code.

```
fftlfsn <- function(H,alpha,m,M,C,N,n){

  mh = 1/m;
  d = H-1/alpha;
  t0 = seq(mh,mh, by =1);
  t1 = seq(1+mh,mh, by=M);
  # Is the following the right way to translate the matlab code into R?
  A = mh^(1/alpha)*matrix(c(t0^d, t1^d-(t1-1)^d), ncol = length(t0), nrow = length(t1));
  C = C*(sum(abs(A)^alpha)^(-1/alpha));
  A = C*A;
  Na = m*(M+N);
  # I don't konw if it is right to use the function "fft" here. 
  #Does this respond directly to the function "fft" in matlab?
  A = fft(A,Na);
  #how can I do somthing similar in R? 
  #I think they create an empty matrix? Could I just write y=0?
  y = [];
    for (i in 1:n)
  {
      if(alpha<2){ 
# The function "rstab" generates symmetric alpha-stable variables. Is there a similar function in R, or do you know how to write one?
        Z = t(rstab(alpha,0,Na))
      }
        else if(alpha==2){ 
          Z = matrix (rnorm(Na, mean = 0, sd = 1), nrow = 1, ncol = Na)
        }
# Again, can I just use the R-function "fft" directly?
  Z = fft(Z,Na);
  w = Re(fft(Z*A,Na, inverse= TRUE));
#I have trouble understanding the following and therefore I can't translate it. 
  y = [y; w(1:m:N*m)];
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I would consider answering the question if it provided a reproducible example and what the output (of different steps) should look like. If you can break down your question into several small ones that'd be great.

Comment: `[mh:mh:1]` is `seq(mh, 1, by=mh)`